# Error in if/while (condition) {: missing Value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, r-faq

I received this error message:

```
Error in if (condition) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

or

```
Error in while (condition) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

What does it mean, and how do I prevent it?

Comment: The double equals operator can't tolerate an `NA` on either side.  If I define: `x = NA` and then do an `if (x == NA){ ... }` then this error will be thrown at runtime when the parser examines the left hand side of the double equals.  To remedy this error, make sure every variable in your conditional is not NA using `is.na(your_variable)`.

Comment: Amazing, this solved an issue I had with an observe() function on daterangeinputs in shiny.

Answer (score 227, accepted):

The evaluation of `condition` resulted in an `NA`.  The `if` conditional must have either a `TRUE` or `FALSE` result.

```
if (NA) {}
## Error in if (NA) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

This can happen accidentally as the results of calculations:

```
if(TRUE && sqrt(-1)) {}
## Error in if (TRUE && sqrt(-1)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

---

To test whether an object is missing use [`is.na(x)`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/is.na) rather than `x == NA`.

---

See also the related errors:

[Error in if/while (condition) { : argument is of length zero](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12307139/134830)

[Error in if/while (condition) : argument is not interpretable as logical](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27659841/134830)

```
if (NULL) {}
## Error in if (NULL) { : argument is of length zero

if ("not logical") {}
## Error: argument is not interpretable as logical

if (c(TRUE, FALSE)) {}
## Warning message:
## the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Answer (score 10):

I ran into this when checking on a null or empty string

```
if (x == NULL || x == '') {
```

changed it to

```
if (is.null(x) || x == '') {
```

Comment: Fyi, there's also `!(length(x) == 1L && nzchar(x))`

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this same error in my `forloops` with complex `if` statements. I fixed this issue by just wrapping my condition with `isTRUE`.

```
if(isTRUE(condition)==TRUE) {do something}
```

Answer (score 0):

this works with `"NA"` not for `NA`

```
comments = c("no","yes","NA")
  for (l in 1:length(comments)) {
    #if (!is.na(comments[l])) print(comments[l])
    if (comments[l] != "NA") print(comments[l])
  }
```