# Error .. missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, for-loop, message

I have been trying to run this code (below here) and I have gotten that message "Error in if (temp[ii] == 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"...

```
temp = c(2.15, 3.5, 0, 0, 0, 1.24, 5.42, 6.87)
tm = length(temp)
for (i in 1:tm){
    if (temp[i] == 0) {
        counter3 = 1
        last = temp[i - 1]
        for (ii in i + 1:tm){
            if (temp[ii] == 0) {
                counter3 = counter3 + 1
            }
            if (temp[ii] != 0) {
                nxt = temp[i + counter3]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: might help if you a) mentioned the language, B) fixed your formatting.

Comment: -1 for not searching. This has been answered multiple times on this site, R-help, etc. Next time, search for the error before posting a question, you'll likely answer the question faster yourself.

Comment: this question has been answered at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355187/error-in-if-while-condition-missing-value-where-true-false-needed

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that `temp[ii]` is returning `NA` because `ii` goes out of bounds:

```
ii = i + 1:tm     #Your declaration for ii
ii = 1:tm + 1:tm  #Evaluates to
```

So `ii` will definitely be larger than `tm` (and therefore `length(temp)` at some point.

In order to better understand/debug `for` loops, consider printing just the indices:

```
for(i in 1:tm)
{
    print(i)
    for(ii in i + 1:tm)
        print(ii)
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answering, but I still get the same message =/

Comment: When I run that code I get the right answer for 

counter3=3
last=3.5
nxt=1.24

What it is all right! 
the only problem is the message that I have gotten and since Im not familiar with R, it has been hard to fix ! Thank you anyway

Comment: You're not making much sense. Why is it that you have `for(ii in i+1:tm)` instead of just `for(ii in 1:tm)`?

Answer (score 2):

At a guess I'm going to say that this is in `R` - if so I'm guessing that this line:

```
if (temp[i] == 0) (or temp[ii] == 0)
```

is resulting in an `NA`, and `if` conditions must have a `TRUE` or `FALSE` value.

Using a debugger if you can, I'd interrogate the value of  temp[i] before the `if` block.

Answer (score 1):

Difficult without knowing the language, but i think the issue is that the value in ii can be greater than the length of temp when i is at its upper bound. I'd have expected an index out of range or something similar but, without knowing the language, who knows! Hope you get your problem fixed.