# Error: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed in while loop

Tags: r, while-loop

I am trying to write a program using a while loop:

```
n=50
sum=array(0,n)
sum[1]=0
for(k in 1:n)
{
   sum[k+1]=sum[k]+k
   while((sum[k+1]-sum[k])<10)
   {
      print(sum[k+1])
      k=k+1
   }
}
sample=data.frame(Sum=sum) sample
```

its showing:

```
Error in while ((sum[k + 1] - sum[k]) < 10) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Can anyone tell what is wrong with this code?

Comment: what is array ? method ?

Comment: You're modifying your `for` loop counter `k` inside the loop. You probably don't really want to do this.

Comment: What would be an approach to write this program then given that I have to write it using the while statement that I have written.Any suggestion would be of immense help.Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error In R: Missing Value where TRUE/FALSE needed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355187/error-in-r-missing-value-where-true-false-needed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second iteration `sum[k+1] = NA` since it'll be evaluated to:

`(sum[2+1]-sum[1])<10` where `sum[2+1] = sum[3]` is `NA`. So `(sum[k+1]-sum[k])<10` will not be evaluated to one of **TRUE/FALSE**.

```
Iteration (k) | sum[k+1]-sum[k]
--------------+------------------
      1       | sum[2] - sum[1]   They're both known
      2       | sum[3] - sum[2]   What is sum[3]? (NA)
```

Comment: But k in the second iteration is 2 right.SO,when we enter the forloop its first calculating sum[2+1]=sum[2]+2

Comment: No, you're still in the `while` loop, you still didn't calculate `sum[3]` which will be evaluated in the `while` loop.

Comment: What would be an approach to write this program then given that I have to write it using the while statement that I have written.Any suggestion would be of immense help.Thanks!

Comment: You can remove the `for` loop, initialize the first two elements, and write `sum[k+1]=sum[k]+k` in the body of the `while` loop.

Comment: n=50
sum=array(0,n)
sum[1]=0
sum[2]=1

k=1
while((sum[k+1]-sum[k])<10)
{
sum[k+1]=sum[k]+k

print(sum[k+1])
k=k+1
}
}
you mean this??but in the second iteration when k=2,sum[2+1] will be NA

Comment: It won't be NA since before you enter the `while` loop it'll have the value of `sum[2] + 2`.

Comment: n=50
sum=array(0,n)
sum[1]=0
sum[2]=1

k=1
while((sum[k+1]-sum[k])<10)
{
sum[k+1]=sum[k]+k

print(sum[k+1])
k=k+1
}
its showing Error in while ((sum[k + 1] - sum[k]) < 10) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: Try to place `k = k + 1` in the first line in the loop.