# Nested If statements in R

Tags: r, function, if-statement, for-loop, nested

I have a function in R that evaluates several if statements within an if statement. It's returning an error message when I run it (I'm only including the sketh of the code, because the actual function is quite big):

```
if (X_star - x != 0){
if (w == 1){
  #stuff 
  } else {
    #stuff 
  if (X_star == 1){
    #Stuff
    } else {
      #Stuff
      }
  #Stuff
  }
Y = something   
if (Y == 1){
  #Stuff
  } else {
    #Stuff
  }
} else {
  if (Xmax - x !=0){
    Y = something else       
    if (Y == 1){
      #Stuff
      } else {
        #Stuff
      }
    } else {
      #Stuff
    }
  }
```

Error:

```
Error in if (X_star - x != 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed.
```

I read some other posts where people seemed to have the same problem, but I couldn't find a definitive answer. I've stared at it for some time but can't find what is wrong with it. This function is located within a for loop, so I can't really use the vectorized ifelse. I'd appreciate any help.

Cheers,

Napo

Comment: Look at the result of `X_star - x`. It looks to me that it is taking on a `NA` value at some point.

Comment: Did you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355187/error-in-if-while-condition-missing-value-where-true-false-needed ?

Comment: what are the values of `X_star` and `x`?

Comment: @ujjwal: Agree that this is unclear. Suggest vote to close.

Comment: X_star and x are integers (taking any value from 1 to 7). It is part of an Reversible jump MCMC implementation. I agree that this is vague. I could post the entire function, but I'm affraid it'll be a bit too long (the function is around 100 lines long and consists of some other functions within it). Thanks

Comment: You may think `X_star` and `x` are integers, but clearly they are not.  Either they're empty or they are of some other `class` .  Please post reproducible data; also post the results of `str(X_star)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with learning how to debug your programs.  Here is a sentence from "?options"

The functions dump.frames and recover provide alternatives that allow post-mortem debugging. Note that these need to specified as e.g. options(error = utils::recover)

Use the options function noted above  and then on the error you can examine the contents of the objects and you will probably see that one of them is NA.  I have that function call at the start of each session to catch errors like this.

Comment: Hi Jim,  how ya been?  :-)