# Error with gamsel R Package

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the gamsel R package to fit a sparse generalized additive model, and I can't seem to get it to work on real data. When I run on synthetic data as described in the package documentation, everything works well:

```
library(gamsel)
data=gendata(n=500,p=12,k.lin=3,k.nonlin=3,deg=8,sigma=0.5)
attach(data)
bases=pseudo.bases(X,degree=10,df=6)
gamsel.out=gamsel(X,y,bases=bases)
```

But when I run on real data, I get the following error:

```
library(gamsel)
X = as.matrix(read.csv("X.csv"),header=FALSE)
y = as.matrix(read.csv("y.csv"),header=FALSE)
gam_fit = gamsel(X,y)
```

> Error in if (abs((df - current.df)/df) < 1e-04 | iterations == 1)
>   return(list(lambda = lambda,  :    missing value where TRUE/FALSE
>   needed

You can access sample data files that will reproduce this result [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_-_1cItR1P4WGdUUllxdGZsUE0&usp=sharing). Any thoughts about how to fix this error?

Comment: I get the same problem with my real data too.  It seems to be part of `df.inv` which is called by `pseudo.bases`.  https://github.com/cran/gamsel/blob/master/R/df.inv.R.  If I work it out I'll post an answer, even though this is a little elderly as a question.

Comment: Could it be a division by zero? I notice some zeros in your `X`, and the error occurs in a line that divides by `df`. An `NA` in an `if` statement could cause this error message: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355187/error-in-if-while-condition-missing-value-where-true-false-needed

Comment: Anybody knows how the lambda is used inside the `gam` function of the `mgcv` library?