# Error message when using Specpool in Vegan Package

Tags: r, vegan

I'm trying to calculate species richness and chao for a list of sites. However I keep getting this error message:

```
Error in if (a2 > 0) var.chao[is] <- a1 * ssc * (0.5 + ssc * (1 + aa/4) *  : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I'm not completely sure what the error message is trying to imply. Specpool works with the same dataset when trying to find the values of an country (for example) just not when I use the sites category.

I can put up dataset if needed.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: The error message is trying to imply that there's a missing value where it needs to see TRUE or FALSE. The only place that seems relevant is `if (a2 > 0)`. Can you post a minimal working example that gives the error? My guess is that `a2 > 0` evaluates to something other than TRUE or FALSE, like NA.

Comment: I think your question has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355187/error-in-if-while-condition-missing-value-where-true-false-needed

Comment: It may be answered in principle. In practice, we would like to catch these situations in **vegan** before they give a cryptic error message. For this we need to be able to reproduce the problem, and a reproducible example is what we need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had some cases with one sampling unit per class. The `specpool` function is based on presence/absence data and numbers of species frequencies in a collection of sampling units. With only one site, you cannot have but frequency = 1, and some of the indices (Chao, 2nd order Jackknife) need the number of doubletons (= number of species occurring in two sampling units). Although the extrapolated richness cannot be estimated from a single sampling unit in `specpool`, such cases should be handled smoothly. The github version of **vegan** now handles those cases, and I have scheduled release of **vegan** 2.3-3 next week with this fix. The one-sampling-unit cases will now return the non-extrapolated observed number of species with standard error = 0 for all indices.

You seem to have classes with either one or two sampling units. Although extrapolated species richness can be estimated for two sampling units, I would not trust such extrapolations: you need larger collections (and if you read carefully the `specpool` documentation *and* the articles referenced therein, you may see that we do not have much trust in these extrapolations in general).

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the issue was. I had one site where I had only recorded one species which made the Chao calculation impossible.

Comment: Calculation may be impossible, but **vegan** should  handle such cases smoothly. I have tried with particularly fabricated data to reproduce your problem, but I have never succeeded in generating error. Could you provide a data set where this error occurs so that we can fix **vegan** if needed?