# Error in View() data.frame containing int64 in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, int64

I've noticed a problem when attempting to `View()` data.frames/.tables with `int64` columns in RStudio (using v0.99.892, but problem is not version specific).

```
> dt2
   a          b          c
1: 1 -126208802   84258755
2: 2 -126194884 1402875037
3: 3 -126199178         NA
4: 4 -126198991  778459540
5: 5 -126200004   42143878

> dput(dt2)
structure(list(a = 1:5, b = c(-126208802L, -126194884L, -126199178L, 
-126198991L, -126200004L), c = structure(c(4.16293562068544e-316, 
6.93112361189968e-315, 0, 3.8461011539138e-315, 2.08218423023247e-316
), class = "integer64")), .Names = c("a", "b", "c"), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000230788>)

> View(dt2)
Error in if (col_min < col_max) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

> View(as.data.frame(dt2)) # maybe it's data.table? -- nope
Error in if (col_min < col_max) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

> View(dt2[,1:2, with=FALSE]) # works if you drop the int64 column
```

The following question does not address these particular circumstances:  [Error in if/while (condition) {: missing Value where TRUE/FALSE needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355187/error-in-if-while-condition-missing-value-where-true-false-needed)

My current workaround is just to drop the int64 columns:

```
View2 <- function(dt){
  View(dt[, which(sapply(dt, class) != "integer64"), with=FALSE])
}
```

But I work with big integers a lot (typically as keys) and it would be super helpful to be able to just View() the darn things.  Any advice?

I'm running R 3.2.3 on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: I can't reproduce in RStudio 0.99.465 R 3.2.3 on Windows 7 x64

Comment: @HubertL thanks for trying -  it's a subset of a table generated by `fread()`... do you think there's any value in posting a sanitized version of the original csv, or does `dput()` capture everything

Comment: Hello from RStudio -- we think this may be fixed in our current preview release (we made a fix for large values in the viewer recently). Give it a try? https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/

Comment: @Jonathan thanks for the comment -- I will give it a try tomorrow and update here

Comment: @Jonathan sorry I never got back to you on this, but this issue was resolved in Windows RStudio sometime between 0.99.892 (question)  and 1.0.153 (what I'm on now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jonathan mentioned in comments, RStudio made a fix for large values in the viewer.  The solution is to [update RStudio](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/).