# Error in if (xn == xx) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r

I'm trying to combine a large number of raster tiles to a single mosaic using R codes as follows. The **error** that appears is:

> Error in if (xn == xx) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

The error appears after the for loop.

I will highly appreciate your suggestion.

```
require(raster)
rasters1 <- list.files("D:/lidar_grid_metrics/ElevMax", 
                   pattern="*.asc$", full.names=TRUE, recursive=TRUE)
rast.list <- list()
   for(i in 1:length(rasters1)) { rast.list[i] <- raster(rasters1[i]) }

rast.list$fun <- mean
    rast.mosaic <- do.call(mosaic,rast.list)
plot(rast.mosaic)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7355187/3358272.

Answer (score 1):

First a better way to write what you do (use lapply)

```
library(raster)
ff <- list.files("D:/lidar_grid_metrics/ElevMax", 
                   pattern="\\.asc$", full.names=TRUE, recursive=TRUE)
rast.list <- lapply(ff, raster)

rast.list$fun <- mean
rast.mosaic <- do.call(mosaic,rast.list)
```

Now, to the error your get. It is useful to show the results of `traceback()` after the error occurs. But from the error message you get, I infer that one of the RasterLayers has an extent with an `NA` value. That makes it invalid. You can check if that is true (and if so figure out what is going on) by doing

```
t(sapply(rast.list, function(i) as.vector(extent(i))))
```

***EDIT***

With the files Ram send me I figured out what was going on. There was a bug when creating a RasterLayer from an ascii file with the native driver if the file specifies "xllcenter" rather than "xllcorner".

This is now fixed on the development version (2.9-1) available on [github](https://github.com/rspatial/raster).

The problem can also be avoided by installing `rgdal` because if `rgdal` is available, the native driver won't be used.

Comment: Hi Rob,
Thank you for your inputs. The same code works fine on another machine but not on the machine on which I work. The results of traceback() after the error are
19: .local(x, ...)
18: extent(object)
17: extent(object)
16: methods::validObject(extent(object))
15: validityMethod(as(object, superClass))
14: anyStrings(validityMethod(as(object, superClass)))
13: validObject(.Object)
12: initialize(value, ...)
10: methods::new("RasterLayer", extent = ext, nrows = nrows, ncols = ncols, 
        crs = crs)
9: .local(...)

Comment: t(sapply(rast.list, function(i) as.vector(extent(i)))) returns [1, ]

Comment: Adding "rgdal" package to solved the problem. Thanks,

Comment: Ah, so these are ascii files that gdal can read, but the native raster code fails. --- it would be helpful if you could point me to (or send m)e one of these files

Comment: Hi Rob, Sure I will send you one of the ascii files. How do you want me to send the file (via email)?

Comment: Yes, if the file is small enough. Else perhaps add a link to your post