# Calculate for all columns in R

Tags: r, multiple-columns, na

I have a data.frame as follows. For every column, I want to assign a value of '1' if the value falls in the range between 2.5 percentile (>=) [second last column] and 97.5 percentile (<=) [last column]. If not, then I want to assign a value 2. At places where there are NAs, I want to let the NAs just be.

```
> df
              S1    S2    S3    S4    S5    S6    2.5%  97.5%
Gene1         0.02  0.04  0.05  0.03  0.10  0.06  0.01  0.08
Gene1         0.04  0.04  0.04  0.06  0.03  0.04  0.03  0.09
Gene1        51.00 57.00  50.00 54.00 70.00 63.00 41.00 71.00
Gene1         0.46  0.35  0.28  0.41  0.26  0.29  0.21  0.45
Gene1         0.09  0.08  0.09  0.09  0.08  0.09  0.07  0.10
Gene1        46.80 44.60  48.40 45.30 40.90 46.10 36.69 49.20
Gene1           NA    NA  20.30 14.10 12.10 15.50  8.72 25.61
Gene1         1.96  1.05  1.39  1.56  1.54  1.71  1.24  2.00
Gene1         0.53  0.52  0.61  0.83  0.73  0.37  0.36  0.91
Gene1         1.05  0.55  0.85  1.30  1.14  0.64  0.61  1.39
Gene1        22.31 28.88  26.75 25.08 26.29 23.34 19.76 33.44
```

So in the end, I want a data.frame that looks like this.

```
> df_updated
              S1  S2  S3  S4  S5  S6
Gene1         1   1   1   1   2   1
Gene1         1   1   1   1   1   1
Gene1         1   1   1   1   1   1
Gene1         2   1   1   1   1   1
Gene1         1   1   1   1   1   1
Gene1         1   1   1   1   1   1
Gene1        NA  NA   1   1   1   1
Gene1         1   2   1   1   1   1
Gene1         1   1   1   1   1   1
Gene1         2   2   1   1   1   1
Gene1         1   1   1   1   1   1
```

I tried something like follows, but ended up with an error. I learnt from here ([Error in if/while (condition) {: missing Value where TRUE/FALSE needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355187/error-in-if-while-condition-missing-value-where-true-false-needed)) that this is related to the NAs that I have in the matrix, but I am not sure how to adapt by code for it, and to get the dataframe 'df_updated' I want.

```
df_updated <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) if (x>=df$`2.5%` & x<=df$`97.5%`) {x==1} else {x==2}))

Error in if (x >= df$`2.5%` & x <= df$`97.5%`) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

Any help appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you have a `data.frame`? That looks like it might be a `matrix` given that you have repeating row names. Are you able to `dput(df)` here so we know exactly what you are working with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't think you'll require `sapply`/`lapply` or any kind of loop here. You could directly compare the values in the dataframe with a column. You get your expected output except for `FALSE` values which could be converted using `replace`.

```
cols <- c(ncol(df) - 1, ncol(df))
df_updated <- df[-cols] >= df[[cols[1]]] & df[-cols] <= df[[cols[2]]]
df_updated <- replace(df_updated, !df_updated, 2)

#      S1 S2 S3 S4 S5 S6
# [1,]  1  1  1  1  2  1
# [2,]  1  1  1  1  1  1
# [3,]  1  1  1  1  1  1
# [4,]  2  1  1  1  1  1
# [5,]  1  1  1  1  1  1
# [6,]  1  1  1  1  1  1
# [7,] NA NA  1  1  1  1
# [8,]  1  2  1  1  1  1
# [9,]  1  1  1  1  1  1
#[10,]  1  2  1  1  1  1
#[11,]  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

Also if you need final output as dataframe you can wrap it in `data.frame()` in the end.

---

A smart one-liner suggested by @thelatemail is

```
(df[-cols] < df[["2.5%"]] | df[-cols] > df[["97.5%"]]) + 1
```

Comment: Too quick for me - here's my variation of similar logic 2 minutes too slow - `vars <- paste0("S",1:6); (dat[vars] < dat[["2.5%"]] | dat[vars] > dat[["97.5%"]]) + 1`

Comment: @thelatemail that is smart. I was trying to squeeze it one line but wasn't successful.

Comment: I had a few attempts before I simplified ;-) Needing the 2/1 order means doing the opposite comparison `< | >` rather than `>= & <=`, but the core idea hopefully is still clear.

Answer (score 4):

To test if your values are in the quantile ranges you can use `ifelse` inside `apply` like:

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
x             S1    S2    S3    S4    S5    S6    x2.5  x97.5
Gene1         0.02  0.04  0.05  0.03  0.10  0.06  0.01  0.08
Gene1         0.04  0.04  0.04  0.06  0.03  0.04  0.03  0.09
Gene1        51.00 57.00  50.00 54.00 70.00 63.00 41.00 71.00
Gene1         0.46  0.35  0.28  0.41  0.26  0.29  0.21  0.45
Gene1         0.09  0.08  0.09  0.09  0.08  0.09  0.07  0.10
Gene1        46.80 44.60  48.40 45.30 40.90 46.10 36.69 49.20
Gene1           NA    NA  20.30 14.10 12.10 15.50  8.72 25.61
Gene1         1.96  1.05  1.39  1.56  1.54  1.71  1.24  2.00
Gene1         0.53  0.52  0.61  0.83  0.73  0.37  0.36  0.91
Gene1         1.05  0.55  0.85  1.30  1.14  0.64  0.61  1.39
Gene1        22.31 28.88  26.75 25.08 26.29 23.34 19.76 33.44")

t(apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) ifelse(x>=x[length(x)-1] & x<=x[length(x)], 1, 2)))[,1:6]
#      S1 S2 S3 S4 S5 S6
# [1,]  1  1  1  1  2  1
# [2,]  1  1  1  1  1  1
# [3,]  1  1  1  1  1  1
# [4,]  2  1  1  1  1  1
# [5,]  1  1  1  1  1  1
# [6,]  1  1  1  1  1  1
# [7,] NA NA  1  1  1  1
# [8,]  1  2  1  1  1  1
# [9,]  1  1  1  1  1  1
#[10,]  1  2  1  1  1  1
#[11,]  1  1  1  1  1  1
```