# for loop conditional based on prior row

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a data base with plays of a football game in order of each play. I want to make a for loop that checks if the play before a field goal (one row up) was a timeout by the other team. I tried using [i - 1] below but not sure if that works as I get an error.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(example)) {
 if (example$field_goal_attempt[i] == 1 & example$timeout[i-1] == 1 & example$timeout_team[i-1] != 
example$posteam[i-1]) {
example$iced[i] == 1
} else {
 example$iced[i] == 0
}
}

example <- data.frame(game_id = c(10,10,10,10,10,13,13,13,13,13), 
field_goal_attempted = c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0), time_out = 
c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), posteam = 
c("PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","ATL","ATL","WAS","WAS","WAS"), timeout_team 
= c(NA, NA, "TEN",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))
```

Show in New WindowClear OutputExpand/Collapse Output
Error in if (example$field_goal_attempt[i] == 1 & example$timeout[i -  : 
  argument is of length zero

Comment: Start from 2: `2:nrow(example)`

Comment: what is example$iced? the code says: if what is inside the "if-condition" is true print whether "example$iced[i] == 1" is true or not. Is that what you are trying to accomplish. You are just trying to evaluate that condition?

Comment: 2:nrow(example) worked without error and works if only game is considered. but for multiple games in one data frame it comes back with : "Error in if (example$field_goal_attempt[i] == 1 & example$timeout[i -  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

Answer (score 0):

You can essentially look at the logic of your problem two ways:

1. The `for` loop goes over the plays, as it does in your case - that is, `i` represents a play that is a field goal and `i-1` represents the previous play. As suggested by `@SmokeyShakers`, you'd start from 2:

```r
for (i in 2:nrow(example)) {
 if (example$field_goal_attempt[i] == 1 && example$timeout[i-1] == 1 && example$timeout_team[i-1] != example$posteam[i-1]) {
  example$iced[i] <- 1
 } else {
 example$iced[i] <- 0
 }
}
```

*Note that I also suggest that you use `&&` instead of `&`, as in the former case, the logical statements are evaluated one by one and stop at the first one that is `FALSE`, while the latter (`&`) evaluates all the parts of the `if` statement, even after it encounters a false one, thus wasting computational time.*
*Additionally, as suggested by `@Jorge` in the comments, I also replaced the `==` with the assignment operator, `<-`, as it seems to me that you'd like to assign `1` or `0`, not evaluate a logical statement whether `example$iced[i]` is equal to `1` or `0`, respectively.*

2. The other way to look at this is to consider the potential timeout as represented by `i`, goal attempt is `i+1`, and your loop needs to terminate earlier by 1:

```r
for (i in 1:(nrow(example)-1)) {
 if (example$field_goal_attempt[i+1] == 1 && example$timeout[i] == 1 && example$timeout_team[i] != example$posteam[i]) {
  example$iced[i+1] <- 1
 } else {
 example$iced[i+1] <- 0
 }
}
```

Comment: Regarding your comment above: *...but for multiple games in one data frame it comes back with : "Error in if (example$field_goal_attempt[i] == 1 & example$timeout[i - : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed* - how do you store and then go over multiple games in one data frame?

Comment: basically there are thousands of games in this df and once one ends the next just starts with the first play in the row below the prior games last play.

Comment: Error in if (example$field_goal_attempt[i] == 1 && example$timeout[i -  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: I see - is there any column in the data frame indicating which game it is? Could you post an example of what the important part of the data frame looks like? I would suggest that you add another condition to check that both lines `i` and `i-1` (or `i` and `i+1`, if you go the second route), come from the same game.

Comment: yes, game_id is a numeric column for each game. I'm not as worried about adding another condition bc there cant be a game starting with a fg so I don't think that will be an issue.

Comment: Sounds like your error is now related to this post: [Error in if/while (condition) {: missing Value where TRUE/FALSE needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355187/error-in-if-while-condition-missing-value-where-true-false-needed). Are you sure you don't have a typo in any of the column names and that all the columns/rows have values in them?

Comment: OK added some example data of just five plays for two games (gameid 10 and 13) to give you an idea of what the relevant columns would look like

Comment: mmm yes there are NA's as in the example. So i need to recode all NAs then?

Comment: I'm looking at your example now and from what you posted, there seem to be a few typos: `example$field_goal_attempt` should be `example$field_goal_attempted` and `example$timeout` should be `example$time_out`. Additionally, yes - when you try running just `example$timeout_team[i-1] != example$posteam[i-1]`, it evaluates to `NA` and not `TRUE` or `FALSE`, so replacing the `NA`s with something else might help, too. When I make these changes, your code runs fine for me and I get a `1` in the `iced` column where it should be.