# Twin primes less than 87 in R

Tags: r, primes

I am trying to list the first 87 twin primes. I'm using the Eratosthenes approach. Here is what I've worked on so far

```
Eratosthenes <- function(n) {
  # Return all prime numbers up to n (based on the sieve of Eratosthenes)
  if (n >= 2) {
    sieve <- seq(2, n) # initialize sieve
    primes <- c() # initialize primes vector
    for (i in seq(2, n)) {
      if (any(sieve == i)) { # check if i is in the sieve
        primes <- c(primes, i) # if so, add i to primes
        sieve <- sieve[(sieve %% i) != 0] # remove multiples of i from sieve
      }
    }
    return(primes)
  } else {
    stop("Input value of n should be at least 2.")
  }
}

Era <- c(Eratosthenes(87))
i <- 2:86

for (i in Era){
  if (Era[i]+2 == Era[i+1]){
    print(c(Era[i], Era[i+1]))
  }
}
```

First thing I dont understand is this error:

```
Error in if (Era[i] + 2 == Era[i + 1]) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Second thing is in the list there are missing twin primes so for example (29,31)

Comment: print `i` for each iteration, I think you will see the problem, also you need to do one fewer iteration than the length of `Era`, that is causing your error

Comment: Except for [3, 5] all twin prime pairs are of the form [6n-1, 6n+1].  That might speed up your search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your `for` loop, `i` is not index any more but the element in `Era`. In this case, you can try using `(i+2) %in% Era` to judge if `i+2` is the twin

```
for (i in Era){
  if ((i+2) %in% Era){
    print(c(i,i+2))
  }
}
```

which gives

```
[1] 3 5
[1] 5 7
[1] 11 13
[1] 17 19
[1] 29 31
[1] 41 43
[1] 59 61
[1] 71 73
```

---

A simpler way might be using `diff`, e.g.,

```
i <- Era[c(diff(Era)==2,FALSE)]
print(cbind(i,j = i+2))
```

which gives

```
> print(cbind(i,j = i+2))
      i  j
[1,]  3  5
[2,]  5  7
[3,] 11 13
[4,] 17 19
[5,] 29 31
[6,] 41 43
[7,] 59 61
[8,] 71 73
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, (23,29) is not twin prime.

Secondly, your answer may be found in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355187/error-in-if-while-condition-missing-value-where-true-false-needed)

Edit: I've tried your code, I found that length of Era is 23.

Maybe when running `if (Era[i] + 2 == Era[i+1])`, it reaches to 24 and causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`for (i in Era)` will set `i` to `2`, then `3`, then `5` etc which is not what you intended. Use `for (i in seq_len(length(Era) - 1))`.

```
for (i in seq_len(length(Era) - 1)){
  if (Era[i] + 2 == Era[i + 1]){
    print(c(Era[i], Era[i + 1]))
  }
}
#> [1] 3 5
#> [1] 5 7
#> [1] 11 13
#> [1] 17 19
#> [1] 29 31
#> [1] 41 43
#> [1] 59 61
#> [1] 71 73
```