# Error in if (condition) {: missing Value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r

I would like to create a new column `esg.ordered$flowpct <- esg.ordered$flow[i]/lag(esg.ordered$size[i])` for my data frame `esg`  only if the value (/name) in a certain row has the same value (/name) as in the previous row in column `fundid`. Otherwise the value in column flowpct should have "NA" in the respective rows. Here is my code:

```
for (i in esg.ordered) {
  if(esg.ordered$fundid[i]==lag(esg.ordered$fundid[i],n=1)){
    esg.ordered$flowpct <- esg.ordered$flow[i]/lag(esg.ordered$size[i])
  }else{
    esg.ordered$flowpct <- "NA"
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, I get two mistakes:

1. Error in if (esg.ordered$fundid[i] == lag(esg.ordered$fundid[i], n = 1)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
2. Warning: In if (esg.ordered$fundid[i] == lag(esg.ordered$fundid[i], n = 1)) { : the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Can you guys help me solving these mistakes?

Here is the data

| fundid | size | flow |
| --- | --- | --- |
| FS00008KNP | 78236537 | 7038075.43 |
| FS00008KNP | 73048868 | -5691940.56 |
| FS00008KNP | 74688822 | -193188.79 |
| FS00008KNP | 95330799 | 11991514.11 |
| FS00008L0W | 44170465 | -15706588.66 |
| FS00008L0W | 33278560 | -12749545.90 |
| FS00008L0W | 26084262 | -6879079.19 |
| FS00008L0W | 23857701 | -3227825.03 |

Comment: Can you provide us with a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You also appear to be attempting to store both chracater and numeric values in `flowpct`.  That's likely to cause problems later on.  Some sample data would help us to help you.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help you create a minimum working example.  Finally, a good rule of thumb when using R is "if I'm using a loop, there's probably a better way to do it.  This, I suspect, is a case in point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `"NA"` is not the same as `NA` (which might be appropriate there.
2. `for (i in esg.ordered)` is wrong: it is iterating over each *column* in your frame named `esg.ordered`, so `i` is a full vector. I think you mean `for (i in seq_len(nrow(esg.ordered)))`.
3. The error `missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed` is easily searched and should return (among other links) [Error in if/while (condition) {: missing Value where TRUE/FALSE needed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7355187/3358272). It is because the conditional in `if` is returning `NA`.
4. You appear to be doing something on a whole vector at a time, this is a literal translation of what you are trying to do (but without the `for` loop):

   ```r
   esg.ordered$flowpct <- ifelse(
     c(TRUE, esg.ordered$fundid[-1] == esg.ordered$fundid[-nrow(esg.ordered)]),
     esg.ordered$flow / c(NA, esg.ordered$size[-nrow(esg.ordered)]),
     NA)
   esg.ordered
   #       fundid     size        flow      flowpct
   # 1 FS00008KNP 78236537   7038075.4           NA
   # 2 FS00008KNP 73048868  -5691940.6 -0.072752972
   # 3 FS00008KNP 74688822   -193188.8 -0.002644651
   # 4 FS00008KNP 95330799  11991514.1  0.160552996
   # 5 FS00008L0W 44170465 -15706588.7           NA
   # 6 FS00008L0W 33278560 -12749545.9 -0.288644140
   # 7 FS00008L0W 26084262  -6879079.2 -0.206712045
   # 8 FS00008L0W 23857701  -3227825.0 -0.123746075
   ```

   However, the relies wholly on `fundid` being ordered correctly. I think a safer way to go is this, using `ave` to get the last `size` within the current `fundid`, and then dividing:

   ```r
   esg.ordered$flowpct <- with(esg.ordered,
     flow / ave(size, fundid, FUN = function(z) c(NA, z[-length(z)])))
   ```

   Same results as above, but much safer.

Comment: Thank you for helping me :) trying my best to understand your suggestions and I will give you my data in a sec

Comment: See the edit. This is still a dupe of the two links provided (the error and the warning), I suggest you click on the dupe-links and read up on several of the excellent answers/comments about the problems. As for the calculation itself, I offer two suggestions, I urge you to use the second (`ave`) as it is much more robust to ordering of the data (i.e., `fundid` does not need to be contiguous/ordered).

Comment: Thank you so much again, I have tried your suggestion and it works! You really saved the day!! :)