# R - Function over rows of dataframe error True/False

Tags: r, dplyr

Trying to create a function that if a != b then it return b else returns a null value then cbind this to the original dataframe.

However getting the following errors:
"argument is of length zero"

Would appreciate any help - similar function in python works fine.

DataFrame is pretty simple

colid col1 col2.  expected output

1. ```
        Blue  Blue
   ```
2. Blue  Blue  Null
3. Red   Blue  Blue
4. ```
              Null
   ```

````
library(readr)
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)

df <- read_csv('/Users/david/Downloads/trustdata.csv')
df_dups <- df[!duplicated(df), ]

wins = function(a,b) {
  if(NULL) return(NULL)
  else if(a != b) {return (b)}
  else {return ("NULL")}
}


df_wins <- apply(df, 1, function(x) wins(x["col1"],x["col2"])) ```
````

Comment: maybe you meant `if(is.null(a)){...}` ?

Comment: Thanks now I am getting the following error. " Error in if (a != b) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed "

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7355187/4137985

Comment: Thanks doesn't seem to help