# Missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed error in smcure model

Tags: r, survival, weibull

I'm creating a cure model in R to predict Loan Default. I'm seeking someone to help me debug this error. I think it may have to do with my columns.

```
library(smcure)

smcure(Surv(DURATION, DEFAULT) ~ CHK_ACCT+HISTORY+NEW_CAR+USED_CAR+FURNITURE+`RADIO/TV`+EDUCATION+
RETRAINING+AMOUNT+SAV_ACCT+EMPLOYMENT+INSTALL_RATE+MALE_DIV+MALE_SINGLE+MALE_MAR_or_WID+
`CO-APPLICANT`+GUARANTOR+PRESENT_RESIDENT+REAL_ESTATE+PROP_UNKN_NONE+AGE+OTHER_INSTALL+RENT+
OWN_RES+NUM_CREDITS+JOB+NUM_DEPENDENTS+TELEPHONE+FOREIGN, 

cureform=~CHK_ACCT+HISTORY+NEW_CAR+USED_CAR+FURNITURE+`RADIO/TV`+EDUCATION+RETRAINING+AMOUNT+SAV_ACCT+
EMPLOYMENT+INSTALL_RATE+MALE_DIV+MALE_SINGLE+MALE_MAR_or_WID+`CO-APPLICANT`+GUARANTOR+PRESENT_RESIDENT+
REAL_ESTATE+PROP_UNKN_NONE+AGE+OTHER_INSTALL+RENT+OWN_RES+NUM_CREDITS+JOB+NUM_DEPENDENTS+
TELEPHONE+FOREIGN,
model="ph", data = CD)
```

> Error in while (convergence > eps & i < emmax) { :
> missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Does anyone know what this error may mean?

Attached I have a subset of the data I used.

##### Data

```
structure(list(CHK_ACCT = c(0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 3, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 
3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 2, 1, 
1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 0, 3, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 3, 0, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0, 1, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 
0, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 0, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1
), DURATION = c(6, 48, 12, 42, 24, 36, 24, 36, 12, 30, 12, 48, 
12, 24, 15, 24, 24, 30, 24, 24, 9, 6, 10, 12, 10, 6, 6, 12, 7, 
60, 18, 24, 18, 12, 12, 45, 48, 18, 10, 9, 30, 12, 18, 30, 48, 
11, 36, 6, 11, 12, 24, 27, 12, 18, 36, 6, 12, 36, 18, 36, 9, 
15, 36, 48, 24, 27, 12, 12, 36, 36, 36, 7, 8, 42, 36, 12, 42, 
11, 54, 30, 24, 15, 18, 24, 10, 12, 18, 36, 18, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
24, 12, 54, 12, 18, 36, 20, 24, 36, 6, 9, 12, 24, 18, 12, 24, 
14, 6, 15, 18, 36, 12, 48, 42, 10, 33, 12, 21, 24, 12, 10, 18, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 48, 36, 15, 18, 60, 12, 27, 12, 15, 12, 6, 
36, 27, 18, 21, 48, 6, 12, 36, 18, 6, 10, 36, 24, 24, 12, 9, 
12, 24, 6, 24, 18, 15, 10, 36, 6, 18, 11, 24, 24, 15, 12, 24, 
8, 21, 30, 12, 6, 12, 21, 36, 36, 21, 24, 18, 15, 9, 16, 12, 
18, 24, 48, 27, 6, 45, 9, 6, 12, 24, 18), HISTORY = c(4, 2, 4, 
2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 4, 0, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 4, 
4, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 
4, 2, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 0, 0, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 2, 3, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 
2, 2, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 0, 4, 2, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 4, 
4, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 3, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
2, 2, 2, 4, 3, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 0, 
2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 3, 1, 4, 4, 4, 1, 4, 2, 0, 2, 0, 
2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3), NEW_CAR = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), USED_CAR = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), FURNITURE = c(0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1), `RADIO/TV` = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), EDUCATION = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0), RETRAINING = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), AMOUNT = c(1169, 
5951, 2096, 7882, 4870, 9055, 2835, 6948, 3059, 5234, 1295, 4308, 
1567, 1199, 1403, 1282, 2424, 8072, 12579, 3430, 2134, 2647, 
2241, 1804, 2069, 1374, 426, 409, 2415, 6836, 1913, 4020, 5866, 
1264, 1474, 4746, 6110, 2100, 1225, 458, 2333, 1158, 6204, 6187, 
6143, 1393, 2299, 1352, 7228, 2073, 2333, 5965, 1262, 3378, 2225, 
783, 6468, 9566, 1961, 6229, 1391, 1537, 1953, 14421, 3181, 5190, 
2171, 1007, 1819, 2394, 8133, 730, 1164, 5954, 1977, 1526, 3965, 
4771, 9436, 3832, 5943, 1213, 1568, 1755, 2315, 1412, 1295, 12612, 
2249, 1108, 618, 1409, 797, 3617, 1318, 15945, 2012, 2622, 2337, 
7057, 1469, 2323, 932, 1919, 2445, 11938, 6458, 6078, 7721, 1410, 
1449, 392, 6260, 7855, 1680, 3578, 7174, 2132, 4281, 2366, 1835, 
3868, 1768, 781, 1924, 2121, 701, 639, 1860, 3499, 8487, 6887, 
2708, 1984, 10144, 1240, 8613, 766, 2728, 1881, 709, 4795, 3416, 
2462, 2288, 3566, 860, 682, 5371, 1582, 1346, 1924, 5848, 7758, 
6967, 1282, 1288, 339, 3512, 1898, 2872, 1055, 1262, 7308, 909, 
2978, 1131, 1577, 3972, 1935, 950, 763, 2064, 1414, 3414, 7485, 
2577, 338, 1963, 571, 9572, 4455, 1647, 3777, 884, 1360, 5129, 
1175, 674, 3244, 4591, 3844, 3915, 2108, 3031, 1501, 1382, 951, 
2760, 4297), SAV_ACCT = c(4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 4, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 4, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 
4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 4, 0, 0, 4, 
0, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 0, 4, 
0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 4, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 3, 0, 
4, 1, 0, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 4, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 4, 
4, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 3, 2, 
4, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
4, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 4, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 4, 0), 
    EMPLOYMENT = c(4, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2, 3, 0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 
    2, 2, 4, 1, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 4, 1, 2, 2, 
    4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4, 0, 2, 2, 1, 4, 
    2, 2, 4, 2, 0, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4, 4, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 4, 2, 4, 4, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3, 1, 
    4, 4, 1, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
    0, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4, 
    3, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3, 2, 4, 1, 3, 0, 4, 2, 
    0, 1, 3, 4, 4, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 4, 3, 4, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 
    2, 4, 0, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 1, 4, 4), INSTALL_RATE = c(4, 
    2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 1, 4, 2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 
    4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 1, 4, 2, 
    4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 4, 4, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 2, 2, 
    3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 
    2, 2, 2, 1, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 
    4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 3, 4, 3, 
    4, 4, 2, 1, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 1, 4, 2, 4, 
    2, 4, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 1, 4, 3, 4, 2, 1, 4, 
    2, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4, 1, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 
    3, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4, 1, 2, 
    4, 4, 2, 4, 2, 1, 4, 4, 4), MALE_DIV = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1), MALE_SINGLE = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
    1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
    1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
    0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
    0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), 
    MALE_MAR_or_WID = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `CO-APPLICANT` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), GUARANTOR = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), PRESENT_RESIDENT = c(4, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    2, 4, 2, 1, 4, 1, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 4, 1, 2, 
    4, 3, 2, 4, 3, 2, 2, 4, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 2, 2, 4, 1, 4, 4, 2, 
    4, 4, 2, 1, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4, 1, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 
    4, 4, 2, 1, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 3, 2, 
    2, 2, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 
    2, 1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 3, 
    2, 4, 1, 3, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 
    2, 4, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2, 4, 3, 1, 
    4, 4, 3), REAL_ESTATE = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), PROP_UNKN_NONE = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), AGE = c(67, 22, 49, 45, 53, 35, 
    53, 35, 61, 28, 25, 24, 22, 60, 28, 32, 53, 25, 44, 31, 48, 
    44, 48, 44, 26, 36, 39, 42, 34, 63, 36, 27, 30, 57, 33, 25, 
    31, 37, 37, 24, 30, 26, 44, 24, 58, 35, 39, 23, 39, 28, 29, 
    30, 25, 31, 57, 26, 52, 31, 23, 23, 27, 50, 61, 25, 26, 48, 
    29, 22, 37, 25, 30, 46, 51, 41, 40, 66, 34, 51, 39, 22, 44, 
    47, 24, 58, 52, 29, 27, 47, 30, 28, 56, 54, 33, 20, 54, 58, 
    61, 34, 36, 36, 41, 24, 24, 35, 26, 39, 39, 32, 30, 35, 31, 
    23, 28, 25, 35, 47, 30, 27, 23, 36, 25, 41, 24, 63, 27, 30, 
    40, 30, 34, 29, 24, 29, 27, 47, 21, 38, 27, 66, 35, 44, 27, 
    30, 27, 22, 23, 30, 39, 51, 28, 46, 42, 38, 24, 29, 36, 20, 
    48, 45, 38, 34, 36, 30, 36, 70, 36, 32, 33, 20, 25, 31, 33, 
    26, 34, 33, 26, 53, 42, 52, 31, 65, 28, 30, 40, 50, 36, 31, 
    74, 68, 20, 33, 54, 34, 36, 29, 21, 34, 28, 27, 36, 40), 
    OTHER_INSTALL = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
    1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0), RENT = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), OWN_RES = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
    0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
    1, 0, 0, 1), NUM_CREDITS = c(2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
    1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
    2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 
    2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
    2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 
    1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 
    2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 1, 1), 
    JOB = c(2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 
    2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 
    1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 
    3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 
    2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 0, 
    2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3), NUM_DEPENDENTS = c(1, 
    1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
    1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), TELEPHONE = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
    1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
    1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    1, 1, 0, 1, 1), FOREIGN = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    DEFAULT = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
    1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-200L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: (1) We don't have your data so we are unable to reproduce any of this. (2) If `while (convergence > eps & i < emmax)` is not anywhere in *your* code, then either your data is not what you think it is (perhaps a name is different or a column's class is different) or this is a bug report to the package maintainer. Most of the time with main-stream packages, it is the former, but I have no idea about `smcure` (first time I've seen it). (3) Either way, at its _root cause_ this problem is https://stackoverflow.com/q/7355187/3358272, whether a dupe or just the indicator.

Comment: @r2evans I added the data

Comment: Your problem is a bit deep-reaching: I loaded `smcure` and debugged its inner (unexported) function `em` that has the [failing line of code](https://github.com/cran/smcure/blob/a14a76c0c472aef21d4a67f90ed0cb7a6e09a29d/R/em.R#L12). Right off the start, its internal `survival`, `w`, and `update_cureb` all have significant counts of `NA`; I haven't looked at it enough to know what is expected, but specifically `update_cureb` suggests that the model is over-fitted, not enough observations per level to be able to regress or substantiate what you need.

Comment: But I think I'm not the right person to help resolve this issue: I'm not familiar with `smcure` or its assumptions, and I know nothing about the data.