# How can I conditionally assign values to a column in data.table using a function that contains 'if' statements and the shift function?

Tags: r, data.table

I want to conditionally generate output in a column based on values in two other columns using data.table. This is something I want to achieve using a function containing 'if' statements specifically, as I'm just trying to learn how to use data.table. The if statement contains `shift()`, and I think that this may be the cause of my problems.

What I have tried so far is the following:

```
library(data.table)

#Data

DT <- data.table(V1 = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 20, replace = TRUE),
                 V2 = sample(1:5, 20, replace = TRUE))

#function

fun1 <- function(x, y){
  if(x == "C" & shift(y,  type = "lead") > y){
    return("Greater")
  } else if(x == "C" & shift(y,  type = "lead") < y){
    return("Lesser")
  } else{
    return(NA)
  }
}

#function implementation

DT.v1 <- DT[, V3 := mapply(fun1, x = V1, y = V2)]
```

If I run the above, I get the error:

```
Error in if (x == "C" & shift(y, type = "lead") > y) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I had an inkling that this error may be caused by comparison with `NA` in the last iteration as `shift(y, type = "lead")` would equal `NA`. Addition of the condition `!is.na(shift(y, type = "lead"))` in the 'if' statement did stop the error from appearing but leads to generation of only `NULL` values.

I have been able to generate my desired output (see script below) but would also like to learn how i can achieve this using 'if' statements in a function.

```
DT.v2 <- DT[V1 == "C" & shift(V2, type = "lead") > V2, V3 := "Greater"][
            V1 == "C" & shift(V2, type = "lead") < V2, V3 := "Lesser"]

#or an alternative way to generate the desired output:

DT.v3 <- DT[, V3 := ifelse(V1 == "C" & shift(V2, type = "lead") > V2, "Greater",
                           ifelse(V1 == "C" & shift(V2, type = "lead") < V2, "Lesser", NA))]
```

Can someone help me understand how to implement the function in a correct way? Thanks for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `mapply` subsumes the ability of `shift` to see data around the row you're working on.

Incidentally, I'm replacing the single-`&` in the `if` statements with `&&`, you should never use `&` there unless it is aggregated, e.g., within `sum`, `any`, `all`, etc. (See [Difference between Boolean operators && and & and between || and | in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6558921/3358272) for a discussion on the differences.)

One way to approach this is to pass the shifted data as an argument to your function:

```r
set.seed(42)
DT <- data.table(V1 = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 20, replace = TRUE),
                 V2 = sample(1:5, 20, replace = TRUE))

fun2 <- function(x, y, shifty) {
  if (x == "C" && isTRUE(shifty > y)) {
    return("Greater")
  } else if (x == "C" && isTRUE(shifty < y)) {
    return("Lesser")
  } else{
    return(NA)
  }
}

DT[, V3 := mapply(fun2, x = V1, y = V2, shifty = shift(V2, type="lead"))]
#         V1    V2      V3
#     <char> <int>  <char>
#  1:      A     4    <NA>
#  2:      A     5    <NA>
#  3:      A     5    <NA>
#  4:      A     5    <NA>
#  5:      B     4    <NA>
#  6:      B     2    <NA>
#  7:      B     4    <NA>
#  8:      A     3    <NA>
#  9:      C     2  Lesser
# 10:      C     1 Greater
# 11:      A     2    <NA>
# 12:      A     3    <NA>
# 13:      B     2    <NA>
# 14:      B     4    <NA>
# 15:      B     4    <NA>
# 16:      C     2 Greater
# 17:      C     5  Lesser
# 18:      A     4    <NA>
# 19:      A     5    <NA>
# 20:      C     4    <NA>
#         V1    V2      V3
```

The use of `isTRUE` in this `fun2` is to account for the condition where `shifty` will be `NA`; another way to avoid this is to use `shifty=shift(V3, type="lead", fill=0)` where `0` is some meaningful number to the context of the data and analysis.

In case you don't *need* to use a function, another option is to use `fcase`:

```r
DT[, V5 := fcase(
    V1 == "C" & shift(V2, type="lead") > V2, "Greater",
    V1 == "C" & shift(V2, type="lead") < V2, "Lesser" )]
```

One interesting thing about the use of `fcase` as opposed to the base `if` statements: with `if`, if any of the operands are `NA` and you don't explicitly account for this, then the condition itself will be `NA` causing the `if` statement to fail (see [Error in if/while (condition) {: missing Value where TRUE/FALSE needed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7355187/3358272)). This is not true with `fcase`:

```r
if (NA == 1) 2 else 3
# Error in if (NA == 1) 2 else 3 : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
fcase(NA == 1, 2, TRUE, 3)
# [1] 3
```

Relatedly, while `ifelse` does not fail, it also does not necessarily work as we want, whereas `fifelse` gives us the option to deal explicitly with `NA` conditions:

```r
ifelse(NA == 1, 2, 3)
# [1] NA
fifelse(NA == 1, 2, 3)
# [1] NA
fifelse(NA == 1, 2, 3, 4)
# [1] 4
```

This is suggested by the formals (and documented in the docs):

```r
formals(ifelse)
# $test
# $yes
# $no
formals(fifelse)
# $test
# $yes
# $no
# $na
# [1] NA
```

Comment: Thanks for the insightful answer! I didn't know about `fcase` and `fifelse`. These seem to be a great way to deal with `NA` operands.

Comment: They are the `data.table` equivalents of (if you use it) `dplyr`'s `case_when` and `if_else`, all of them aiming to improve the performance and class-safety of `base::ifelse` (and no "case" variant in base, not directly at least). Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

---

The main issue,on top of the NA issue that you rightly pointed out is that the if statement requires condition of length one

```
a <- 1:10
> if(a>5)
+ { print("hello")}
Error in if (a > 5) { : the condition has length > 1
```

And the `fun1` is passing a vector -
*update* fun1 is not passing a vector see comment below.

In my opinion  your second option is the right way to do the job.

```
DT.v2 <- DT[V1 == "C" & shift(V2, type = "lead") > V2, V3 := "Greater"][
            V1 == "C" & shift(V2, type = "lead") < V2, V3 := "Lesser"]
```

This is less error prone. If you really need to use if else statement I would suggest checking `?fcase`.

Comment: Your first assertion is not true. By using `mapply`, the OP is passing length-1 arguments to `fun1`. You can verify this with `debug(fun1)` then looking at `x` and `y` when you try the OP's code.