# Bootstrapping error: Error in if (const(t, min(1e-08, mean(t, na.rm = TRUE)/1e+06))) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r

I am running a function (`rcompanion::cramerV`) that uses `boot.ci` to generate CIs. I am getting the error message:
`Error in if (const(t, min(1e-08, mean(t, na.rm = TRUE)/1e+06))) { :  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed` but I'm not sure how to fix it.

It's failing on a specific matrix:

```
> bad_data <- matrix(c(31, 0, 46, 0, 1, 0), nrow=3, ncol=2)
> bad_data
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   31    0
[2,]    0    1
[3,]   46    0
```

When I call `cramerV` without CIs, it computes fine (yielding V = 1, which I recognise is statistically questionable), but when I call it with CIs e.g. `cramerV(bad_data, ci=TRUE)` it gives me that error. Happens regardless of `type` of CI specified.

Obviously there are some statistical issues here but that's not my focus; I'm running `cramerV` on hundreds of small matrices at once and a couple of outlier results is fine. I just need to know how to get it to work computationally (and maybe return `NA` for the CIs in this case).

Edit: I understand that what's happening is the `if` condition is evaluating to `NA` (per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355187/error-in-if-while-condition-missing-value-where-true-false-needed)), but I don't know why that's happening or what's going on under the hood with `boot.ci` or most importantly how to prevent it.

Comment: @jay.sf why would the second column be converted to entirely zeroes?

Comment: It's very likely that the second column gets entirely zeroes if the second row doesn't get resampled in a [bootstrap](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)) replication w/replacement. What then internally happens is e.g. `chisq.test(c(31, 31, 46), c(0, 0, 0))`. In one of the packages you use, this case is not taken into account, resulting in a bad error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of the function.

***Amendment:***

I updated the function to avoid this error.  The following code will load the updated version from the internet.  I'll update the function in the package at a later date.

In the updated version, if the bootstrapped values are all equal, it returns a data frame with the Cramer's *V* value,  and *NA* for the confidence internal limits.

```
bad_data <- matrix(c(31, 0, 46, 0, 1, 0), nrow=3, ncol=2)

library(boot)

source("http://rcompanion.org/r_script/cramerV_2023_06_15.r")

cramerV(bad_data, ci=TRUE, histogram=TRUE)

cramerV(bad_data, ci=TRUE, reportIncomplete=TRUE, histogram=TRUE)
```

Compare:

```
bad_data_3 <- matrix(c(31, 0, 46, 1, 1, 0), nrow=3, ncol=2)

library(boot)

source("http://rcompanion.org/r_script/cramerV_2023_06_15.r")

cramerV(bad_data_3, ci=TRUE, histogram=TRUE)

cramerV(bad_data_3, ci=TRUE, reportIncomplete=TRUE, histogram=TRUE)
```

***Original response:***

I think the solution provided by @TYLim is a good one for this application.

The `cramerV()` function has a provision to prevent errors in the case of the resampling producing, in this case, all zeros in the second column.

For example, the following will return a small data frame, but with `NA`'s for the confidence interval.

```
bad_data_1 <- matrix(c(31, 0, 46, 1, 1, 0), nrow=3, ncol=2)

library(rcompanion)

cramerV(bad_data_1, ci=TRUE)
```

Or it can be forced to produce the confidence interval for the resampled cases where there are not all zeros in the second column with the `reportIncomplete` option.

```
cramerV(bad_data_1, ci=TRUE, reportIncomplete=TRUE, histogram=TRUE)
```

In the case of the original `bad_data` matrix, the error appears to occur in the `boot()` call.  As far as I can tell, it's because all the values for Cramer's *V* would be 1 for all the valid cases.  I might be able to develop a solution to the problem in the function, but it doesn't occur often.  The solution @TYLim suggests is probably the best approach, and would come into play only in specific and extreme cases.

Comment: Thanks @SalMangiafico and thanks for creating the function in the first place!

Could you comment a bit on using `reportIncomplete` - what are potential downsides there?

Comment: I added an amendment to my response with an updated function.

Comment: In the case of the `cramerV()` function, the function will report `NA` for the confidence interval limits if any of the bootstrap iterations have all zeros in any row or column.  The `reportIncomplete` option simply ignores these cases, and returns the confidence interval for the cases that don't meet this criterion.  This would bias the results in some way.  Ex., for `bad_data`, it's only going to include iterations where that `1` is included in cell (2, 2).  This only comes up in sparse tables or small samples sizes, where, honestly, the bootstrapped CI's probably aren't very valid anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Not a full solution, but recognising that sometimes the bootstrapping fails for reasons as outlined by @jay.sf, I created a workaround using `tryCatch`:

```
cramerV_errorhandling <- function(.x, ci=TRUE, ...) {
  if (ci==TRUE) {
    error_output <- data.frame(Cramer.V=NA, lower.ci=NA, upper.ci=NA)
  } else {
    error_output <- data.frame(Cramer.V=NA)
  }
  tryCatch(cramerV(.x, ci=ci, ...), error = function(e) error_output)
}
```

Note that the `rcompanion::cramerV` function returns either a single value if `ci=FALSE` or a dataframe of three values if `ci=TRUE`.

This version just returns a single or three-value dataframe of `NA` if `cramerV` runs into errors.