# R crashes when using moveVis in R

Tags: r, crash

I have an R script that I have used several times to animate different animal species tracking data. The script is quite basic but for me it does the trick. I have tried to use it recently and the first problem I have encountered is that the [Package ‘moveVis’ was removed from the CRAN repository](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/moveVis/index.html) and could not be loaded. To overcome the issue I have reinstalled it from Github through:

```
install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("16eagle/moveVis")
library(moveVis)
```

The installation goes well and I can run my code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(move)
library(moveVis)

#read the data in
data <- read.csv(file.choose())
#View(data)

#convert character string date time to a date.time class
data$Date.time <- as.POSIXct(data$Date.time, tz = "GMT")

#create a new column with date only and time only
data$date <- as.Date(data$Date.time, "GMT")
data$time <- strftime(data$Date.time, format = "%H:%M:%S")

# Make sure points are in order (in case they weren't before)
data <- data %>%
  arrange(ID, date, time) %>% # arrange by animal, and ascending date and time
  filter(!is.na(x),!is.na(y)) # remove NA's

#Use Movevis to  make the animaion
#convert the data to a move object
data.m <-
  df2move(
    data,
    proj = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84",
    x = "x",
    y = "y",
    time = "Date.time",
    track_id = "ID"
  )

# check the sampling rate
lag <- unlist(timeLag(data.m, unit = "mins"))
median(lag)
sd(lag)
# sampling rate is 3 hours and do not differ over time. this is because in this case I am using interpolated track data at three hours intervals

# align data.m to a uniform time scale
m <- align_move(data.m, res =180 , unit = "mins")
length(unique(timestamps(m)))

#define a manual extent for which we want to animate:
ext <- extent(m)*1.1

# create spatial frames with a OpenStreetMap watercolour map
#use get_maptypes() to check for available maps
frames <-
  frames_spatial(
    m,
    ext = ext,
    path_colours = c("green", "red", "yellow", "black", "pink", "purple", "orange", "darkred", "darkgreen", "gray", "navy"),
    map_service = "osm", 
    map_type = "topographic",
    path_size = 2,
    alpha = 0.75,
    path_legend = F
      ) %>%
  add_labels(x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude") %>% # add some customizations, such as axis labels
  add_northarrow() %>%
  add_scalebar() %>%
  add_timestamps(type = "label") %>%
  add_progress()

frames[[100]] # preview one of the frames, e.g. the 100th frame

# animate frames
animate_frames(frames, out_file = "moveVis7.gif", width=1000, height= 1000, res= 100)
```

The data.frame has the following structure:

```
'data.frame':   2105 obs. of  14 variables:
 $ X                  : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ ID                 : int  212759 212759 212759 212759 212759 212759 212759 212759 212759 212759 ...
 $ step               : num  26.42 8.58 18.91 19.13 17.75 ...
 $ angle              : num  NA -0.593 -1.949 -0.514 -0.874 ...
 $ Date.time          : chr  "2021-05-08 17:00:00" "2021-05-08 20:00:00" "2021-05-08 23:00:00" "2021-05-09 02:00:00" ...
 $ zone               : int  18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 ...
 $ x                  : num  1.64 1.94 2.04 1.89 1.68 ...
 $ y                  : num  41 41.1 41.1 40.9 40.9 ...
 $ state_2st          : chr  "Transit" "ARS" "ARS" "ARS" ...
 $ StateProbs.ARS     : num  0.208 0.981 1 0.96 0.991 ...
 $ StateProbs.Transit : num  7.92e-01 1.88e-02 1.31e-12 4.01e-02 9.48e-03 ...
 $ slope.deg          : num  90 90 90 90 90 ...
 $ depth.m            : int  -353 -553 -598 -1191 -993 -400 -147 -83 -85 -98 ...
 $ dist.to.close.coast: num  18580 18201 22838 33868 35828 ...
```

I have no errors except for R crashing without explanations, due to a fatal error, after running:

```
frames <-
  frames_spatial(
    m,
    ext = ext,
    path_colours = c("green", "red", "yellow", "black", "pink", "purple", "orange", "darkred", "darkgreen", "gray", "navy"),
    map_service = "osm", 
    map_type = "topographic",
    path_size = 2,
    alpha = 0.75,
    path_legend = F
      ) %>%
  add_labels(x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude") %>% # add some customizations, such as axis labels
  add_northarrow() %>%
  add_scalebar() %>%
  add_timestamps(type = "label") %>%
  add_progress()
```

The progress bar reaches 100% and then R crashes. I have tried this on different machines in RStudio and directly in R but the result is the same. What could be causing the crashing?

Comment: I found movevis and the associated basemaps package started having issues several months ago with how it downloads and plots the basemaps.  I have found using the fix posted by Zross in this thread fixed the issue with the basemaps.  You could try installing his fork instead of the cran version of basemaps and se if it fixes the issue with movevis.  https://github.com/16EAGLE/basemaps/issues/22

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @BEVAN for pointing to the workaround. I removed the basemaps package,  and installed the fork by [Zoss](https://github.com/zross/basemap-fork).

```
remove.packages("basemaps")
.rs.restartR()
remotes::install_github("zross/basemap-fork")
library(basemaps)
```

However, although R does not crash now, I have the following message.

```
Checking temporal alignment...
Processing movement data...
Approximated animation duration: ≈ 34.12s at 25 fps for 853 frames
Retrieving and compositing basemap imagery...
Loading basemap 'topographic' from map service 'osm'...
  |==============================================| 100% elapsed=01s  
Assigning raster maps to frames...
Error in if (row1 == 1 & row2 == nrow(x) & col1 == 1 & col2 == ncol(x)) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I have checked for solutions to the error and it [seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355187/error-in-if-while-condition-missing-value-where-true-false-needed) that the error appears when an if conditional does not have a TRUE or FALSE result. Given that I am not using any if conditional, I would think that hat the basemaps/terra packages still have issues. Thanks for advices.