# error message: error in if (any(ind4<-(kmat<small.size))){:missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, count, regression, modeling, vgam

My count data fits a negative binomial, death counts, with no zero deaths, mean  predominantly lower than variance, so I suspect overdispesion, so I use Zero truncated negative binomial using VGAM package. Now am getting this : error in if (any(ind4<-(kmat<small.size))){:missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed.
What does it mean? How to fix it?

Attempted Zero Truncated Poisson, error too

Comment: This kind of issue is regularly discussed:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355187/error-in-if-while-condition-missing-value-where-true-false-needed