# In R, Warning messages: 1: In sum(mhtable[, 1, i]) * sum(mhtable[1, , i]) : NAs produced by integer overflow

Tags: r, statistics, chi-squared

I'm trying to do a Cochran-Mantel-Haenzel test to see if sex modifies the relationship between cases (whether someone has a condition) and grandmal (outcome = having grand mal status).
head gm

```
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  cases SEX   grandmal
  <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
1     1 M            0
2     1 F            0
3     1 M            0
4     1 M            0
5     1 F            0
6     1 F            0
```

table<-xtabs(~grandmal+cases+SEX, data=gm)
ftable(table)

```
               SEX      F      M
grandmal cases                  
0        0         259471 143343
         1          85749  44601
1        0            587    419
         1            202    122
```

with(gm, mhor(grandmal, cases, SEX))

```
Stratified analysis by  SEX 
                OR lower lim. upper lim. P value
SEX F        1.041      0.883       1.22   0.621
SEX M        0.936      0.758       1.15   0.544
M-H combined 0.999      0.881       1.13      NA

M-H Chi2(1) = NA , P value = NA 
Homogeneity test, chi-squared 1 d.f. = 0.66 , P value = 0.416 

Warning messages:
1: In sum(mhtable[, 1, i]) * sum(mhtable[1, , i]) :
  NAs produced by integer overflow
2: In sum(mhtable[, 1, i]) * sum(mhtable[1, , i]) :
  NAs produced by integer overflow
```

Using the mantelhaen.test results in an error
mantelhaen.test(table)

```
Error in if (correct && (abs(DELTA) >= 0.5)) 0.5 else 0 : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In s.x[1, ] * s.y[1, ] : NAs produced by integer overflow`
```

tried using base mantelhaens.test and epiDisplay, but there is some problem with integer overflow. I tried changing sex to female==1 and male==0 and make them all numeric, but it still returns the same error.

I also removed all NAs

any(is.na(gm))

```
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: The error about `missing value` is likely due to the warning and the `NA` that was produced. For the error, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/7355187/3358272, though depending on where it's happening, you may not be able to affect it atm. As for the warnings about "integer overflow", the typical workaround is convert the errant field from `integer` to `numeric`, but ... your data are `dbl`, and the results from `xtabs` are (afaict) numeric already, not ints.