# "dosresmeta" package: Dealing with missing values in n and cases

Tags: r, missing-data, meta-analysis

In my work I use both STATA and R. Currently I want to perform a dose-response meta-analysis and use the "dosresmeta" package in R. The following syntax is used:

```
DRMeta <- dosresmeta(
formula = logRR ~ dose,
type = type,
cases = n_cases,
n = n,
lb = RR_lo,
ub = RR_hi,
id = ID,
data = DRMetaAnalysis
)
```

When executing this syntax, however, I encounter a problem. The error message appears:

```
Error in if (delta < tol) break : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed.
```

The reason for this error message is that I am missing some values for the variables "n_cases" and "n", which the authors have not provided. Interestingly, STATA does not require this information for the calculation of the dose-response meta-analysis.

Is there a way to perform the analysis in R without requiring the values for "n_cases" and "n"? What can I do if I have not given these values?

I have already asked the authors for the missing values, unfortunately without success. However, I need these studies for the dose-response meta-analysis, so it is not an option to exclude them.

Comment: That error could mean several things, not just that you have `NA` values in your data. To me, that's clearly a bug in the package that must be fixed by the authors, relating to https://stackoverflow.com/q/7355187/3358272.

Comment: While the package was last updated in 2017 (over 6 years ago) and the last commit in 2019, the author responded to an issue in 2022 (albeit 4 months after the issue was created), so perhaps they're still responsive. I suggest you file a [new issue](https://github.com/alecri/dosresmeta/issues/new/choose) with the dev/author to fix the problem. It appears to be [here](https://github.com/alecri/dosresmeta/blob/dcc47a98d2a7181b0d6531893017c066f38b23c7/R/covariance.R#L413). When you do that, make sure to give them sample data so that they can reproduce your problem here. Good luck!